# log last time login in node

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node . What I am trying to implement is to ask a user his name. When the user enters his name his session is created. On behind the time of user login is saved . Next time the user enters his name . His name plus the last time he logged in should be shown . My attempt was this

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere'}));

app.use(bodyParser());

app.all('*', function findLastVisit(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.visited)
    req.lastVisit = req.session.visited;

    req.session.visited = Date.now();


  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
             'Your name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>' +
             '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
             '</form>';
  if (req.session.userName) {
    html += '<br>Your username from your session is: ' + req.session.userName + '<br> And the last time you visited was ' + req.lastVisit;
  }
  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log("server is on 1337 bro");
```

Unfortunately my code always displays the current time only . I think I am doing a silly mistake . can anyone point out ?

Comment: You are missing curly brackets on `if (req.session.visited)`, only the first statement is executed in the if block.

Comment: That is on purpose as one can neglect braces if he wants just the first like to be under the if statement . The other line is just another code which should not be in the if statement

Comment: In this case I recommend you format your code better to improve readability, properly formatted code is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove your middelware and add another variable called `lastVisited` like below

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere'}));

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
             'Your name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>' +
             '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
             '</form>';
  if (req.session.userName) {
    html += '<br>Your username from your session is: ' + req.session.userName + '<br> And the last time you visited was ' + req.session.lastVisited  ; //LOOK here I replaced your variable with lastVisited
  }
  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
  req.session.lastVisited = req.session.visited || Date.now(); //LOOK here
  req.session.visited = Date.now();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log("server is on 1337 bro");
```